# Equating between short form and long form of the same instrument

Tags: continuous-data, psychometrics, test-equating

I have encountered several instruments in psychology and related fields where we have multiple versions of the same instrument, specifically a short form and a long form. For instance, the patient health questionnaire has a 8 item version and a 9 item version. As another example, the perceived stress scale has a 4 item version, 10 item version, and 14 item version. I am trying to create a formula or conversion table that will allow me to move across the different forms.

In my particular case, I am working with a 50 item survey that has a 10 item short form.
All item in the 10 item survey are part of the 50 item survey.  The survey is scored on a Likert scale.

I have two ideas on how to approach this.

The first method is to use test equating, specifically common-item non-equivalent group design.  However, I don't know if this would be appropriate as all 10 items on the short form are on the 50 item long form.

The second method is to run a regression model to see if I can create some predictive formula to allow me to move across forms.

Which method would be the best way to tackle this problem?